# checking exisiting filenames against muliple file input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a file verification process which checks if a filename is already in the database by making an ajax call. This works if there is only 1 filename echoed in existing-filenames.php, but I can't figure out how I can loop through the return data to check every filename in the multiple file input against every result from the existing-filenames.php loop. any advice much appreciated. thanks

```
var file = $('#file')[0];
$.get('existing-filenames.php', function(data){

  for (var i=0; i<file.files.length; i++) {
       var fname = file.files[i].name;

        if(fname == data){ 
          alert("these files already exist:" + data); 
          return false;
        }
      }
  });
```

and in 'existing-filenames.php'

```
$allfiles = $db->query("SELECT filename FROM files WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'");

    while($result = $allfiles ->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $result['filename'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP file you're just printing all file paths without a space or a new line.
Also you should use prepared statements for your query, include `$_SESSION['email']` without any check is not safe at all.

By the way, try edit your PHP file like this:

```
$allfiles = $db->query("SELECT filename FROM files WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'");

$fileList = array();
while($result = $allfiles ->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fileList[] = $result['filename'];
}

echo json_encode($fileList);
```

And your JS code like this:

```
$.get('existing-filenames.php', function(data){
      for (var i=0; i<file.files.length; i++) {
       var fname = file.files[i].name;

        if(data.indexOf(fname) >= 0){ 
          alert("these files already exist:" + data); 
          return false;
        }
      }
  }, 'json');
```

Not tested, but it should work

Comment: thanks, works great. Do you happen to know how to make it so that it only lists the files which ave been selected. right now if the alert is triggered it will list all the files.

Comment: the file input is like this:                                      <input name = "file[]" type = "file" id = "file" multiple />

Comment: well, I would just check `fname.length`. Selected files should have non-empty file names.

Comment: good idea, i'll try that now. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your JS to:

```
var file = $('#file')[0];
$.getJSON('existing-filenames.php', function(data){

  for (var i=0; i<file.files.length; i++) {
     var fname = file.files[i].name;

      if(~data.indexOf(fname)){ 
        alert("these files already exist:" + data); 
        return false;
      }
  }
});
```

And in your PHP file:

```
$result = [];
while( $files = $allfiles ->fetch_assoc() ){
    $result[] = $files['filename'];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

... I think. I hardly ever write PHP.

Comment: `fname == data[i]` will check just 1 element of `data` list

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileNames = $('.file-name').text();

fileNames.forEach(function(fileName){
     $.get('url',{filename: fileName},function(data){
                  ....
       });
 });
```

My approach would be getting the filenames into an array and making the get request with different parameters each time